# Understanding a function that finds the longest key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The `find_longest` method in the following `dict` class finds the longest key value inside the dictionary.

```
class LongestKey(dict):
    def find_longest(self):
        longest = None
        for key in self:
            if not longest or len(key) > len(longest):
                longest = key
        print(key)

a = LongestKey()
a["hi"] = 1
a["hello"] = 2
a["hey there"] = 3
a["greetings sir"] = 4

a.find_longest()
```

The code is working, but I am having a very hard time undertanding the logic behind the if not or statement. I originally used

```
if len(key) > len(longest):
```

instead of

```
if not longest or len(key) > len(longest):
```

but it produces the error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. Why is this? Thank you very much for enlightening me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need `if not longest` check is because first time the loop is run, `longest` is `None` and you can't do `len(None)`. So you do `if not longest` check and only if  this is `False`, the second condition  is checked.

---

This additional check can be avoided in this case by initialising `longest` to `-1` instead of `None` and comparing `len(key)` with `longest` (not `len(longest)`).

Something like this:

```
class LongestKey(dict):    
    def find_longest(self):
        longest = -1  
        for key in self:
            if len(key) > longest:
                longest = len(key)
                longest_key = key
        print(longest_key)   # <-- print longest key not just key.
```

**Note**: Your code prints only the last key which might not be the longest key every time. In `if`, you need to update longest key along with `longest` value as shown.

Comment: potentially worth having `longest` be initially set to `-1` as strings could have a `len` of `0`

Comment: @aydow, missed that. Thank you.

Comment: **and only if this is False, the second condition is checked.** I had no idea. I was assuming the **or** in the check meant either one could be true independently and the loop would still run. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize the code I posted wasn't actually finding the longest key. Thank you for your example which seems much more clear to me now

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are checking the length of `longest` which is set to `None`. Hence the error.

Example,

```
x = None
print(len(x))

# output
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The reason you don't get the error is because `if not longest` is executed while the second condition `len(key) > len(longest)` is not even executed because first is matched already. On top of that, the reason it works is the value of `longest` changes on second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare the variable `longest` and assign it to `None`

```
def find_longest(self):
    longest = None
```

`NoneType` doesn't have `len()`. So it lead to this statement:

```
if not longest or len(key) > len(longest):
...
```

It checks whether `longest` has been updated or not

Answer (score 0):

It's to prevent an error from occurring during the first iteration of the `for` loop.

The `not longest` part of the logical expression is evaluated first and if it's `True` then the remainder of the expression—the `or len(key) > len(longest)` portion—won't be evaluated and the value of the whole expression will also be `True`.

This is needed because initially `longest` got set to `None`, and writing the logical expression that way prevents the `len(longest)` part of the second half from being evaluated and a `TypeError` occurring because `longest` has no length yet.

Comment: This is the easiest to understand answer I've received on stack exchange. I didn't know that logical expression that precedes the or is or isn't evaluated dependent on the first expression being True or False. Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I will be studying up on it today!

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing:

```
longest=None
```

You are making sure that the object *longest* have '*no value*' or '*empty value*'. In Python we don't need to declare variables first, so there are no really *empty* variables in Python. Setting a variable to *None* is then not the same thing as setting it to a default empty value; None is a value too, albeit one that is often used to signal *emptyness*. 
So how can you count the length of an object if its empty? That's the logic being used here, *longest* doesn't have any value at all so it throws an error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

And when you are using:

```
if not longest or len(key) > len(longest):
```

You are making sure that the object *longest* doesn't have the value *None*.